# Delete query using Listview C#

Tags: c#, sql, listview, webforms, sql-delete

I have a Listview using windows form of C#

```
Id | Name | Age

1      John     18

2      Mark     21
```

How do I put my delete query using the selectedIndex of Listview?

```
string query = "delete from Users where id = '" + *selected index of Listview* + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your query would be like this

```
string query = "delete from Users where id = " + Listview.SelectedValue;
```

However, in your html markup, where you define your `ListView`, make sure to set `DataKeyNames` so that `SelectedValue` will be populated correctly.

Example:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" DataKeyNames="UserId" ...>
```

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the selected value of the listview

```
   ListView.SelectedItems[0].Text
```

if you eant just the index

```
 ListView.SelectedIndex
```

Try this variation for getting the value of selected item,this should work.

Comment: Why -1? hmm, ok dont know if selected index is the right answer for this. but answer editted to clarify.

Comment: Neither `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItems[0].Text` will necessarily give you the ID of the record.  `SelectedIndex` relies on position (not ID), and `SelectedItems[0].Text` displays what the end user sees (formatting and all), not necessarily (and not likely) the ID either.